# Display result of request in different page on JQM/Angular

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a little JQuery Mobile + angular app.

I have index.html page which has few controls. When clicking on the button, I'm calling a function in the $scope of the controller which returns a result.

The thing is that I want to display the results using angular on another page but its not working. It works if I'm displaying the results on the same page(index.html) but doesn't works if I'm moving to another page (lets say results.html) which uses the same controller...

Any idea?

Comment: Same controller does not equal same scope. Each instance of a controller will have its own scope which is why you have nothing to show on your target page.

Comment: I have written a huge Angular/JQM app (50 + pages, 30 + controllers etc) which leverages a lot of nontrivial techniques to solve this issue. Basically, you have to let JQM handle your page routing and communicate that information to the proper controller on your navigation events. I use a 3rd party JQM router to also allow me to pass query parameters on my hash urls so I can pass data to another JQM page. But, before we get into that, what would happen if you wrapped a div around both pages and set your controller on the wrapping div? I think JQM may bomb but I have never tried it.

Comment: ANother alternative is to have your JQM page have a hidden results section where you display your results. When the user clicks the button  you hide your top section and dsiplay the results section. You will have to modify your nav back button so that it does the opposite, hide the resutls section and display the top.